# UITabBarItem title overwritten by UIViewController title?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have setup a UITabBarController with two separate UIViewControllers. In the init for the second UIViewController I am setting the UITabBarItem so it displays the tab correctly:

```
UITabBarItem *tabBar = [self tabBarItem];
[tabBar setTitle:@"DATA"];
[tabBar setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"DATA.png"]];
```

This works fine, the tab shows the title "DATA" and displays the correct icon image. In the same controller inside loadView I am setting the UIViewController title:

```
[self setTitle:@"Data Table"];
```

My question is when I run the application my 2nd tab reads "DATA" however when I click on the tab and loadView is called (I have a UITableView in there) and I set the UNViewControllers title property to "Data Table" my 2nd tab also changes to read "Data Table". Is there a way to fix/avoid this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you sure you want just two UIViewControllers not UINavigationControllers? Usually you create a UIViewController, then create UINavigationController with that view controller, and then put these navigation controllers into UITabBarController.

This way your UIViewController will actually have 'title' which you can change.

Comment: The first tab is a UIMapView, the second tab is a UINavigationController using initWithRootViewController, the root view controller is a UIViewController which has on it (amongst other things) a UITableView.

Comment: then in that second view controller you should do:             self.navigationItem.title = [NSString stringWithString: @"AAAA"];

Comment: Thank you Sha, navigationItem was what I needed, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.title = @"title";
```